# How to change color title bar in MAUI?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, maui, maui-windows

I want to change title bar color like theme color.

[title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D7K4.png)

I get theme color but i dont know how to change the color. I try

```
#if WINDOWS
 var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
 var color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    var titleBar = appView.TitleBar;
    titleBar.BackgroundColor = color;
#endif
```

I get exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Element not found.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document about [Title bar customization in the WinUI3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui3#platform-options), you should use the WinUI3's api to do that. The code you used is for the uwp not the winui3.

So you can try the following code:

```
#if WINDOWS
            var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
            var color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);
            Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
            //get the current window on the windows platform
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
            Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
            Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
            Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowTitleBar titlebar = appWindow.TitleBar;
           //titlebar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
           // in the official document, this line is needed, but when I used it, the background color didn't change
            titlebar.BackgroundColor = color;
#endif
```

I refered to [this issue about customizing the title bar in the maui](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5730). It may provide you more ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much. I add using Window = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window; and vs studio asked to change the encoding to unicode and it worked. Again thank you